# How to calculate sum of CPU usage of users who are not me

Tags: bash, ssh, cpu-usage

I would like a bash command which outputs the sum of the cpu usage percentages of all users who are not me, including users logged in through ssh, screen, and other non-terminal sessions.

Comment: Obvious question, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a command that should do the trick:

```
ps ax -o pcpu:5,user --no-headers | tr -s ' ' | grep -v $(whoami) | cut -d' ' -f2 | (tr '\n' + ; echo 0; ) | bc
```

The `ps` command will list the CPU usages of every process alongside its owner. The `tr` will squeeze together multiple spaces, so the `cut` later on works as wanted. The `grep` will filter out processes owned by you. The `cut` command will select the first column, ie, the CPU usages. The `tr` will substitute new lines for plus signs, and finally `bc` will evaluate the resulting arithmetic expression.

Cheers.